# How to match multiple words?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following wildcard query that works. However sometimes I have a query with multiple words with spaces separated (for example 'green apple', and I need to match records. How can I achieve this?

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "name": {
                            "value": "*uni*"
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Comment: You need wildcard on multiple words or simple match queries, adding sample docs and expected results would help, Added answer based on my understanding but will modify it according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use bool must query with multiple match for ex:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "green"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "apple"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Now as you didn't specify let's take two use cases**

**Index sample docs**

```
{
   "name" : "green apple"
}

{
  "name" : "green"
}

{
  "name" : "apple"
}
```

**case 1: you want both green and apple must present in `name` field**

{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "match": [ --> note this
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "green"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "apple"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

**Search result contains only 1 doc**

```
 "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "boolmatch",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.78038335,
            "_source": {
               "name": "green apple"
            }
         }
      ]
```

**case 2: green or apple should present in the name field**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "green"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "name": "apple"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search result contains all 3 sample**

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "boolmatch",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.78038335,
        "_source": {
          "name": "green apple"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "boolmatch",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.52354836,
        "_source": {
          "name": "green"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "boolmatch",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.52354836,
        "_source": {
          "name": "apple"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```